# What's the best way to have an auto-complete textbox with a filter

Tags: forms, design, input-fields, autocomplete, fields

So basically, what I'm trying to do here is create an auto-complete text field.

However, from the list of options, there are a number of them we're trying to push for and because of this, we'd like to add a filter (checkbox) above the list of options.

Here's a quick example of what I'm trying to illustrate:

1. Default:

[image]

2. When checkbox filter is selected:

[image]

3. As user is typing, suggestions will show up based on their query, but checkbox filter will still be shown above the list. (Unable to post last image since I'm told I needed a Reputation 10 to do that).

Do you think this is the most efficient way of adding that filter or does anyone have suggestions?

Note

Comment: Any reason why the checkbox cannot be placed beside the text box?

Comment: I actually thought of that, but putting the checkbox outside the textarea made it feel like they're both disconnected from each other - like they were both separate, stand-alone form items. When really one is supposed to filter the other.

Answer (score 2):

Like JDanniel Pacheco, i think the best solution would be to group the possible options.

But I would go for something like this:

[image]

Additionally, you can let the user maybe enter the filter themselves like:

[image]

Comment: Yes, those are great suggestions, thanks! I also thought of JDanniel's solution initially where you just group them. My only concern was if the lists get too long.

Comment: That's also a great solution, DennisW, thanks. Do you think it's intuitive enough to know that typing a group heading letter would also return results? I guess you'll find out eventually once you fiddle with it, or mistakenly type the beginning letter of the group heading.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can group your items and you filters like:

[image]